# Как перенести контент из мобильного приложения на сайт (штрих-код Пятёрочки)

Tags: python, php, aiogram

Всем привет, я разрабатываю на коленке свой телеграм бот-магазин, где я продаю цифровые товары (ключи, аккаунты и т.д.)
Я решил продавать динамически меняющиеся штрих-коды скидочных карт магазинов, но аккаунты создаются заранее на левые номера, так что сделать СМС-авторизацию для покупателя либо невозможно, либо слишком дорого.
Суть в том, чтобы как-то переносить данные из эмулятора на сайт, где статичное изображение - бутафория приложения и динамичное - штрих-код (скриншот или сгенерированный из данных).

1. Как заставить Python запустить эмулятор и что-то там понажимать
2. Как Python может "достать" данные из приложения (проверить данные - баланс бонусов, работоспособность; спарсить данные или заскринить)
3. Ну с отправкой на сайт проблем быть не должно

Я уверен, что в большинстве случаев лучше не скринить, а парсить данные, потому что приложения наверняка сами генерируют коды. Могу показать примеры, где это уже работает: боты по продаже карточек и их сайты - x5.app, 5ka.me, franchise.five.codes (Баллы + купоны Пятёрочки), pigfarm.ltd (Макдак, Магнит, Пятёрочка и т.д. даже с возможностью выбора любимых товаров или акций)

И демонстрация: https://t.me/pyaterochka_me/131, https://t.me/pyaterochka_me/255

Спасибо всем, кто ответит!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достать данные из приложения в эмуляторе поможет [appium](https://appium.io/) или что-то ещё в таком роде. Гулгите "mobile app automation".

Это грубо говоря селениум для мобилок. Можете жать кнопки, считывать тексты, делать скриншоты.